# How does the electron configuration correlate with the emission spectrum of an ionic compound?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, spectroscopy, ionic-compounds, elemental-analysis

trying to find a way to correlate the electron configuration of an ionic compound (ie. Cupric sulfate, potassium chloride, Cupric chloride, sodium carbonate, strontium chloride) with its emission spectra.